# best backend framework to use with React frontend

Tags: web-services, laravel, reactjs, sails.js, loopbackjs

i have to developed a web app intregated also with Android Phone.
I have choosen to use react js with redux for the frontend  and native android for mobile app. I need to develop a backend that publish some restfull api and if possible push notification management. The backend should be connected data stores ( i need a framework compatible with mongo db and mysql). I need an high level of performance. The solutions that meet these reqs that i found on the web are:
sails
loopback
laravel
hibernate

What is the best solution that met these reqs and if is compatible with react ?
i need a production solution
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going full API, no HTML involved, [Laravel Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) would be my choice for a RESTful API. It's blazing fast, easy to develop and it's... Laravel! But the "best" always come with some sort of personal preference, right?

When building APIs, what you need to achieve is to have a endpoints (restful) and those endpoints to return JSON. You make a resquest to an URL, and you get a JSON back, as simple as that. This is something you will get with most framerworks out there: Rails (Ruby), Django (Python), Node (Javascript), Slim (PHP), Symfony (PHP), Lumen (PHP), Laravel (PHP), and many many others. Whatever you choose you'll probably have pros and cons, so choose something you like to code with.

[Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport) is  is also something you have to consider those days. It's API authentication done the right way and builtin Laravel 5.3 Framework. So if your app needs Authentication & Authorization, you better consider a framework abe to do that securely via OAuth2.

Comment: Hi thanks! Reading your response .. i ve done some reasearch and i find a lot of god feedback about Lumen ! Some question about Lumen: 1) support oracle DB ?       2)  Is a goodstack lumen for backend  + React  for frontend ?

Comment: You'll find some community packages for Oracle, shouldn't be a problem and I myself have a React App using a Laravel 4.2 as backend, old stuff, about to upgrqde, but very good they play nice

Comment: Why old stuff ? Thereis a tecnology better ?

Comment: Laravel 4.2? Pretty old. We are planning an upgrade to 5.3

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on with what language you are more comfortable with.

If PHP is OK with you. [Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/) is a very robust solution and covers all your requirements. Great community and rich documentation.

Also if performance is a priority, [Lumen 5.3](https://lumen.laravel.com/) is a great lightweight alternative.

Comment: Hi thanks! Reading your response .. i ve done some reasearch and i find a lot of god feedback about Lumen ! Some question about Lumen: 1) support oracle DB ? 2) Is a goodstack lumen for backend + React for frontend ?